# Pausing CSS3 animation after 1 iteration between multiple iterations

Tags: css, iteration, css-animations

In the hope of making a drop-down menu that looks nice using CSS3, I have styled one using animation. I have used animation instead of transition in order to be able to have more control over the timing of the drop. I feel that this is more aesthetically pleasing. However one does run into a problem when using animation over transition, in that the reverse process becomes much harder to animate. I was wondering if there was a way to, effectively pause the animation while using the menu, to have it animate in the reverse, much like it would in a transition.

Here's an idea of what the CSS looks like now:

```
@-webkit-keyframes s-menu-down /*Safari and Chrome */ {
0%   { width: 100%; height: 0px;}
100% { width: 180px; height: 27px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes s-menu-down /*Firefox */ {
    0%   { width: 100%; height: 0px;}
    100% { width: 180px; height: 27px;}
}

@keyframes s-menu-down {
    0%   { width: 100%; height: 0px;}
    100% { width: 180px; height: 27px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes s-menu-down-text /*Safari and Chrome */ {
    0%   { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, .0); text-shadow: none;}
    100% { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, 1.0); text-shadow: rgba(238, 238, 238, 1.0);}
}

@-moz-keyframes s-menu-down-text /*Firefox */ {
    0%   { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, .0); text-shadow: none;}
    100% { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, 1.0); text-shadow: rgba(238, 238, 238, 1.0);}
}

@keyframes s-menu-down-text {
    0%   { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, .0); text-shadow: none;}
    100% { color: rgba(84, 83, 81, 1.0); text-shadow: rgba(238, 238, 238, 1.0);}
}

ul#secondary li:hover > ul li {
    -webkit-animation: s-menu-down .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
    -moz-animation: s-menu-down .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
    animation: s-menu-down .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
}

ul#secondary li:hover > ul li a {
    -webkit-animation: s-menu-down-text .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
    -moz-animation: s-menu-down-text .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
    animation: s-menu-down-text .5s linear 0 2 alternate;
}
```

By setting the CSS to alternate, and by making the repeat 2, I can make the menu go both up and down. I'm looking for some sort of javascript solution, or something else to the effect, to pause in between the iterations to allow the menu use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to pause animation between multiple iteration. Right now, the only solution I found is using jquery code to remove/add CSS classes with animation description. jquery code is dependent on animation time, which is not ideal, but I'm not a jquery master :-)

HTML:

```
<div id="animateTest" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: Orange;">
    <table id="animateTable" class="table90deg" style="border: 2px solid Gray; border-radius: 25px;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Jméno
            </th>
            <th>
                Příjmení
            </th>
            <th>
                Telefon
            </th>
            <th>
                Adresa
            </th>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animationIn
{
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);}
    25%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg);}
    50%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(50deg);}
    75%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationOut 
{
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    25%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg);}
    50%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(50deg);}
    75%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);}
}


.table90deg
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); 
}  

.tablein
{
    -webkit-animation-name: animationIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

.tableout
{
    -webkit-animation-name: animationOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#animateTest").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#animateTable").removeClass("table90deg");
            $("#animateTable").addClass("tablein");

            $("#animateTable").delay(2000).queue(
            function () {
                $("#animateTable").removeClass("tablein");
                $("#animateTable").dequeue();
            });
        });

        $("#animateTest").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#animateTable").addClass("tableout");
            $("#animateTable").delay(2000).queue(
            function () {
                $("#animateTable").removeClass("tableout");
                $("#animateTable").addClass("table90deg");
                $("#animateTable").dequeue();
            });

        });
</script>
```